# How do you switch between two windows in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to make a new PyQt window show up and hide the current window when I click a button. After playing around for hours, I haven't found a good way to do this.

When I try to show a new QDialog and hide the current one, the program closes. It works if another window is open. I believe this is because it is viewing the last window as closing and terminates, or maybe the new QDialog is falling off the stack.

My current method involves storing the QDialog as a variable in the current dialog, then showing it and hiding current dialog. This seems like a total hack, though.

Example below:

```
def _createQuestion(self):
    # initialization of the UI and everything goes on in the constructor
    self.dialog = QuestionBanks()
    self.dialog.show()
    self.hide()
```

Is there a better way of switching a single window to a distinct different single window in PyQt4?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689053/how-to-communicate-or-switch-between-two-windows-in-pyqt4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533625/multiple-classes-in-pyqt4 could also help.

Comment: why exactly is what you've done, a "hack"? What about it do you consider "hacky"?